# Firefox ignores max-height with Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have written the following Flexbox layout:

https://jsfiddle.net/atb5yyez/4/

```css
html, body {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container1 {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  max-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

header {
  background-color: blue;
}

main {
  background-color: red;
  max-heigth: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

footer {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="container2">
    <header>header</header>
    <main>
      content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
      <br>content
    </main>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  <div>
</div>
```

Chrome renders this page correctly: header and footer are sticky and the content takes as much space as possible, while still not taking more than the height of the container.
[image]

With other browsers (Firefox, Edge, Android Browser etc.) the header is still there but the footer is not and the container takes way too much space.
[image]

**Why is this happening? Is Chrome rendering the thing correctly and other browsers have a bug? Or have I done something wrong and Chrome is the only browser which forgives me?**

Now I know I can "solve" this problem by using only one Flexbox container. However, the problem occurred in a real web project and I needed to isolate it to producude the example code. In the real project I need to use two containers so  it should be possible to solve this by keeping both containers in place.

Comment: max-height value are not supposed to be inherited and used by children. beside: height:500px + max-height:300px; is not coherent. and height:100% requires an height with an inheritable value from parent in CSS. If that code works, congratulation to the browser that understood you ;)

Comment: Yes, using a hardcoded height and max-height on the same element was a mistake. I removed the height property.

Comment: i commented a few things https://jsfiddle.net/atb5yyez/6/ and would do this this way https://jsfiddle.net/atb5yyez/7/ i guess you look for main to fill entire space left and scroll if needed ?

Comment: Thanks for help. Your solution seems to fix this problem. :)

Comment: One more question: to my understanding "max-height: 100%" means "at the most 100% of the parent's current height". Even though the parent has no height property set in CSS, the children's max height should be 100% at most. Based on your comments, this is not true, but the max-height is always related to the height CSS property of the parent. Is this correct?

Comment: yep, max-height is related to parent's height set in the CSS style sheet (can be retrieve via js)when percentage is used .https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/max-height

Comment: Okay. Thanks so much for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an incorrect attempt to inherit max-height values and was solved by **GCyrillus** by using flex and height properties.

See:

```
jsfiddle.net/atb5yyez/6
jsfiddle.net/atb5yyez/7
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, as has been stated in a few comments (by GCyrillus), that you're trying to inherit the (max-)height values.

I'm guessing, what you want to be doing, is setting the max-height to 100% of the viewport height?
In that case, you can change all instances of 100% to

```
max-height: 100vh;
```

This sets it to 100 procent of **V**iewport **H**eight.

Also, your html and body have heights set to 500px and then max-heights set to 300px, which seems odd.

If you're trying to keep this max-height of 300px, why don't you just set the max-height of container1, container2 and main to 300px as well?

Comment: this is about our comments :)

Comment: The real problem occurred on my web application which I was browsing with a mobile phone. I set the body height to 300px to simply emulate a mobile viewport height. This was probably a bad idea as it caused some confusion for the people who tried to help me. The final solution should always work regardless of the current viewport height.

Comment: Anyway, I think GCyrrilus found a working solution by using flex and height properties instead of my confusing attempt to inherit max-heights. But thanks for help. :)